# Is it possible to update "Featured Content" in Salesforce Content?

Tags: content, contentversion

Featured Content is a neat way to promote certain items in SFDC Content. From the documentation:

> **Featured Content** This section lists the five pieces of content in your libraries most recently designed as “featured.” Featured content
>   receives a higher priority than similar content in search results; for
>   example, if 100 files contain the search criteria term sales asset,
>   any featured files with that term will appear at the top of the search
>   results list.

I can read this field via SOQL but I'm wondering if it can be edited programmatically. Given the screenshot below I think the answer is 'no' but I'm hopeful :)

Perhaps there's a system method or another field that triggers an update on this one?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've found, I don't think you can update the featured status outside the UI as you can't toggle the FeaturedContentBoost between 0 and 1 due to its Read Only status. The FeaturedContentDate doesn't help as it appears to be set internally based on changes to the former field.

---

If you were really keen and willing to take the risks associated with using unsupported features, you might be able to POST that same JSON message that the website UI does to toggle the value.

> **Request URL:**  https://na5.salesforce.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd
>   **Request Method:** POST
>   **Form Data:**
>       *message:*{"actions":[{"controller":"document","action":"feature","params":{"documentId":"069x00000000ppY","featuredContentBoost":1,"shepherdSuccess":"You have successfully featured this content.","shepherdToken":"rZp.really.long.token.J03k="}}]}
>       *format:*json

The difficult part will be the shepardToken, which is probably there to protect against cross site request forgery and casual hacking.

Comment: @wes did you ever give this a try?  Would love to hear if you'd figured out how to deal with the shepherdToken