# Anyway to hack subscriber users to a piece of content?

Tags: javascript, content

Is there any supported or unsupported way to programmatically subscribe a user to a piece of content?  A related [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/13633/594) suggests that you might be able to hack a post to make a piece of content as featured.  Perhaps a similar approach would work for subscribing a user to a specific content document?